# Associating Windows file extension with specific bat file and support argument passing

Tags: windows-7, python, batch-file, file-association, blender

On my Windows 7 system, I have associated the `.blend` extension with a specific bat file I wrote, which is shown below:

**blender.bat**:

```
set PYTHONPATH=""
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender\blender.exe" "%1"
```

Here's the output of the command `ftype blendfile`:

```
blendfile="C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.bat" "%1"
```

When I double click a .blend file (e.g. `model.blend`), the application (Blender) starts up fine, but the file in question is not opened.  That is, the application starts as if the file `blender.bat` was double clicked by itself.

The file is in the following folder:

> F:\TRAINING_BLENDER\MY MODELS

(Note that the pathname contains spaces)

If I open up a command prompt at the above folder and run the following command:

`model.blend`

I see the following output:

> Error: Cannot read file 'F:\TRAINING_BLENDER\MY': No such file or
>   directory unknown argument, loading as file: - 
>   
>   ...

I understand that the problem is due to the folder name having embedded spaces, but I have the argument specificer (`%1`) in double quotes to protect from that.  What could be the problem?

Disclaimer: I have read this related question: [Double clicking a file in explorer opens the associated application but not the file](https://superuser.com/questions/261448/double-clicking-a-file-in-explorer-opens-the-associated-application-but-not-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Python problem.  Internally, Blender uses Python, and Python does not like pathnames with spaces.  The only solution is to have .blend files in a folder hierarchy without any embedded spaces.  I did this and was able to open files correctly.